# How to refactor long if statements

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have this nested if statement, and i can't figure out how to refactor it... It's properly pretty simple but i just can't get the right idea, hope someone can help.

First i have a nested if statement (bad):

```
unless record.valid?
  if condition_1
    action_1
  elsif condition_2
    action_2
  elsif condition_3
    action_3
  end
end
```

Then i tried this, but that doesn't look any better (if-statement without anything inside is bad too):

```
if record.valid?
  # do nothing
elsif condition_1
  action_1
elsif condition_2
  action_2
elsif condition_3
  action_3
end
```

Do anyone have a idea on how to refactor these statements so it looks better?

### Update: solution (based on @thomasfedb and @undur_gongor)

What i end up doing was simply:

```
return if record.valid?

if condition_1
  action_1
elsif condition_2
  action_2
elsif condition_3
  action_3
end
```

Comment: rewrite to `case/when`? split into methods, pack them into hash, look them up vis some key and just dispatch? refactor into Strategy? there are many ways..

Comment: Is `record` a `Hash` ?

Comment: case/when would not change anything. I would still have a `when record.valid?` without anything inside...

Comment: @OMG `record` is most likely an instance of a Rails model.

Comment: No record is a model record (user). However that doesn't change anything. I have edited my question to show this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might find it's neater if you take advantage of Ruby's various `if`/`unless` syntaxes and the `case` statement. If you were to wrap is in a method you could also take advantage of `return`.

```
def check_record(record)
  return unless record.valid?

  case record.some_property
  when 1
    do_something
  when 2
    do_whatever
  when 3
    do_a_dance
  end
end
```

Comment: If that was what you were looking for then you might mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Sure i'll just wait to see if anyone else have some good suggestion. You say that i could take advantage of `if/unless` too, but i already do this in my first example? I still can't find a way to use `unless` that could help?

Comment: I mean the way that you can write `return unless record.valid?`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Mapping = { :has_value_1? => :method_1, 
            :has_value_2? => :method_2, 
            :has_value_3? => :method_3 }

unless record.valid?
  Mapping.each_pair do | k, v | 
    next unless record.send(k)
    record.send(v)
    break
  end
end
```

Beware, in very old Ruby versions (prior to 1.9) hashes have no ordering. You need an array of pairs in that case if the order of the attributes matters. The remaining code will be pretty much the same.

**After updated question** (and based on [thomasfedb's proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212278/908515)):

```
def check_record(record)
  return unless record.valid?

  return action_1 if condition_1
  return action_2 if condition_2
  return action_3 if condition_3

  nil
end
```

Comment: I can see the point in this refactoring for large if-statements... However i feel that it's a bit overkill for this simple example.

Comment: @jokklan: If the real code is as simple as in your question, I agree. But then, I wouldn't care about refactoring at all and go with the first solution. It is good.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hide all that stuff inside an object.  Don't make clients, especially yourself, repeat this again and again.  Write it once.  Call one method and put all decisions about what to do inside it, hiding it from clients.  The user shouldn't have to check the state to decide what to ask the object to do.  Encapsulate all of that inside the object itself.

Comment: Good idea but it was actually the if statement itself i wanted to improve. I don't like nested if statements, or if's without anything inside..

Comment: I agree, but it's not so bad if you only write it once.  Sometimes you've got to do what has to be done.  The Map idea is a good one if Ruby has functions as objects.